# magento 2: get blank page when checking if category exists in sidebar

Tags: magento2

my current code in sidebar.phtml

```
  <?php

  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category

  if($category->getId()==503){
 echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('automation_tissue_processors')->toHtml();
}
?>
```

when I am on a page with category in breadcrumbs it works fine

```
Home > Instruments > automation-tissue-processors-embedders.html
```

the problem is when there is no category in the breadcrumbs I get a blank page

```
Home > automation-tissue-processors-embedders.html
```

this happens when I click on a product from search result

any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accesing the category>getId() on null object $category that's why it leads to blank page. Just use this code in if codition

if(!empty($category) && $category->getId()==503){
  echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('automation_tissue_processors')->toHtml();
}